# Python QGIS application to exe with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, dll, pyinstaller, exe, qgis

[image]I am trying to create a bundled python qgis(3.10 Crouna - ltr) application with pyinstaller(4.5.1).
When i create the bundle and after i click the Main.exe which is located under dist folder, it gives me the following error.

I used pyinstaller under the QGIS 3.10/apps/python37 Anyone can help?